# Move file but rename if existing in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to move my files in Windows. Currently the files are in a folder under drive C: but I want to move them to a location in D:.

I am using shutil.move function but that function overwrites the file if it is existing. I want to keep a copy of the file in the destination not overwrite it. Is there a function to do that?

```
def movefiles(strsrc, strdest, strextension):
    filelistsrc = []  #source files full path
    # store the destination of the current file
    dictfiles = {}

    for f in os.listdir(strsrc):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(strsrc, f)):
            filefullname = os.path.join(strsrc, f)
            if filefullname.endswith(".html"):
                filelistsrc.append(filefullname)
                dictfiles[filefullname] = os.path.join(strdest, f)

    if not filelistsrc:
        return -1

    print("Start moving files from:")
    printstrlist(filelistsrc)

    for filename in filelistsrc:
        shutil.move(filename, dictfiles[filename])

    return 0
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I added it to the post.

Answer (score 0):

before moving it in the last for-loop you can check if the file already exists and depending of the result moving it. I made an recursive function that checks the name of the files and incrementing it until the filename is new:

```
import os

def renamefile(ffpath, idx = 1):
    
    #Rename the file from test.jpeg to test1.jpeg
    path, ext = os.path.splitext(ffpath)
    path, filename = path.split('/')[:-1], path.split('/')[-1]
    new_filename = filename + str(idx)
    path.append(new_filename + ext)
    path = ('/').join(path)

    #Check if the file exists. if not return the filename, if it exists increment the name with 1    
    if os.path.exists(path):
        print("Filename {} already exists".format(path))
        return renamefile(ffpath, idx = idx+1)
    
    return path

for filename in filelistsrc:
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        renamefile(filename)

    shutil.move(filename, dictfiles[filename])
```

Comment: I just want to auto rename it like windows does. For example:example.txt can be renamed to example2.txt

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution,

```
def move_files(str_src, str_dest):
    for f in os.listdir(str_src):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(str_src, f)):
            # if not .html continue..
            if not f.endswith(".html"):
                continue

            # count file in the dest folder with same name..
            count = sum(1 for dst_f in os.listdir(str_dest) if dst_f == f)
            
            # prefix file count if duplicate file exists in dest folder
            if count:
                dst_file = f + "_" + str(count + 1)
            else:
                dst_file = f

            shutil.move(os.path.join(str_src, f),
                        os.path.join(str_dest, dst_file))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file already exists, we want to create a new one and not overwrite it.

```
for filname in filelistsrc:
    if os.path.exists(dictfiles[filename]):
        i, temp = 1, filename
        file_name, ext = filename.split("/")[-1].split(".")
        while os.path.exists(temp):
            temp = os.path.join(strdest, f"{file_name}_{i}.{ext}")
            dictfiles[filename] = temp
            i += 1
    shutil.move(filename, dictfiles[filename])
```

Check if the destination exists. If yes, create a new destination and move the file.